# Search using elasticsearch (contains)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elasticsearch

I am developing my ASP.NET MVC application called eBookRepository that contains online books. **Ebook** has its own **title, author** etc. So right now I'm trying to implement my search mechanism. I must use Elasticsearch as search engine.

I have **indexed** my ebooks in this code, **and it works.**

```
Uri nodeLocation = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
IConnectionPool connectionPool = new SniffingConnectionPool(new List<Uri> { nodeLocation });
ConnectionSettings settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool).DefaultIndex("ebookrepository");
  esClient = new ElasticClient(settings);

foreach (var ebook in ebooksService.GetAll())
{
            IIndexResponse result = esClient.Index(ebook, i => i.Index("ebookrepository").Type("ebook").Id(ebook.ID));
}
```

Also if I **search** my ebooks by title, it works but only if search text is **exactly same as ebook's title**. Code doing that is here:

```
var search = esClient.Search<Ebook>(s => s.Source(sf => sf.IncludeAll()).Query(q => q.Term(p1 => p1.Title, searchString)));
```

**searchString variable is string (text) that I type in text box on UI.**

So I cant find similiar code like this above that should work like **.contains** method in C#, I was looking for right solution and I think I should use .Match instead of .Term (.Term return exact matching result), but I cant find right solution.

While I was looking for right solution a lot of questions and answers are in JSON format (I'm not good at it), I dont want that format, I need .NET code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation you can use a Unstructured Search https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-queries.html#unstructured-search

Comment: No it's not working. I tried var searchResponse = esClient.Search<Ebook>(s => s.Query(q => q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Title).Query(searchString))));

Comment: Could you try one more query ?

var searchResponse = esClient.Search<Ebook>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Term(p => p.Title, searchString)
    )
);

Comment: No it's not working. .Term returns only exact matching result. I'm using it, I posted code with .Term in my question up.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
var hits = _context.Search<Ebook>(search string, new SearchUrlParameters { Pretty = true });
```

Comment: What is SearchUrlParameters? I got no references to it.

Comment: it's a class of ElasticsearchCRUD.dll

Comment: No its not working. Its red line under .Search<Ebook> and it says "The search API allows to execute a search query ang get back search hits that match the query. No overload for method 'Search' takes 2 arguments